# Returning to exacts view in Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In case Level, I have few List views for example: **All css cases**

I created List button named it  "**TestCheck**". If I click that button,It redirects to new page.

The new page contains Contains cancel button

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.CancelPage}" />
```

If I click on cancel, i will call below method

```
  CancelPage:function(component,event,helper){ 
    //Used Lightnng Out:so Using window.location
    window.location = "/500/o";
  }
```

Problem here is:

```
 Its redirect to 'All recently viewed cases'.
```

Instead of returning to all recently viewed cases,it should return to **All css cases**

Its like I came from All CSS cases view,then it should it returns to that view.

***Note: Use Lightning:Out because of that reason,Using  window.location***. I don't want to use window.history.back(),
.any other way to return to previous page

***Receiving refused to connect error  while back page: //---salesforce.com***

window.location = "/500/o";

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
CancelPage:function(component,event,helper){ 
   window.history.back();
}
```

OR

```
CancelPage:function(component,event,helper){ 
    window.location = "/lightning/o/Case/list?filterName=" + '{IdOftheListView}'
}
```

Here **IdOftheListView** should be the Id you get when you open that list view from UI.

Comment: window.history.back(); isnot a good a solution for me. I tried it & i removed that code. i just tracks the previous information

Comment: Did you try the second solution ??

Comment: Thisurl will not change: /lightning/o/Case/list?filterName=??? & also i will click vf page then opening Lightning components.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using force:navigateToList, its fires an event to navigate to a specific listview. You will have to provide list view id and it should navigate to that list view.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToList/specification

Comment: It is not supported in Lightning Out.